# How to hook into Drupal 6 search process?

Tags: 6, hooks, search

I need to modify the search results drupal generates to include selected content from some other D6 sister sites.  `hook_search` seemed like the obvious choice, but when I implement it, it's never invoked with the keywords I'm searching for:

```
function nmc_xsearch_search( $op = 'search', $keys = NULL ) {

    switch ($op) {

        case 'name':
            return t('Content');
            return $form;

        case 'search':    
            dsm( "Operation: $op | Keys: $keys" );        
                return $results;
    }
}
```

When I walk through this code in the debugger, my function nmc_xsearch_search() is hit twice.  The first time $op = 'name' and $keys = null.  The second time $op = 'name' and $keys = '1'.

When I put a breakpoint on `node_search` it is invoked four times - all before my nmc_xsearch_search() is hit.  The last time node_search is hit the provided parameters are: $op = 'search' and $keys = 'my search keywords'.

Basically I want my function to get the same invocation that `node_search` is getting so that I can access the keywords and modify the results array returned by hook_search.  Any ideas?

Comment: To whoever briefly posted a helpful answer: please un-delete it, it was just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [`search_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.module/function/search_menu/6), you will notice the following code.

```
  foreach (module_implements('search') as $name) {
    $items['search/' . $name . '/%menu_tail'] = array(
      'title callback' => 'module_invoke',
      'title arguments' => array($name, 'search', 'name', TRUE),
      'page callback' => 'search_view',
      'page arguments' => array($name),
      'access callback' => '_search_menu',
      'access arguments' => array($name),
      'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
      'parent' => 'search',
      'file' => 'search.pages.inc',
    );
  }
```

Every module implementing `hook_search()` gets a menu tab. So, your module will be asked to search only when the users select its tab.